# mypy does not recognize the correct return type

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to load credentials into my program from different sources. If one source does not have 'valid' credentials (in my case valid credentials are all tuples of two non empty strings), try the next source until you get a valid credential (or the sources run out).

I wrote a method (`validate`) that checks if credentials are valid and returns them if that is the case and `None` otherwise:

```py
MaybeCredentials = Optional[Tuple[Optional[str], Optional[str]]]


def validate(credentials: MaybeCredentials) -> Optional[tuple[str, str]]:
    if is_valid_credentials(credentials):
        return credentials
    return None


def is_valid_credentials(credentials: MaybeCredentials) -> bool:
    return isinstance(credentials, tuple) and \
           len(credentials) == 2 and \
           is_valid_string(credentials[0]) and \
           is_valid_string(credentials[1])


def is_valid_string(string: Optional[str]) -> bool:
    return isinstance(string, str) and not string.strip() == ''
```

The code works perfectly fine (tests at the end), however when I check `mypy`, it shows this error:

```
Incompatible return value type (got "Optional[Tuple[Optional[str], Optional[str]]]", expected "Optional[Tuple[str, str]]")
```

for my `validate` method. How can I let mypy know that when `is_valid_credentials` returns true, `credentials` is of type `tuple[str, str]`? Also, is `validate` a good name for the method?

And is this the correct forum for this type of question? The code is working after all.

Tests:

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize('credentials,expected', [
    ((), False),
    (('',), False),
    ('', False),
    (1, False),
    (None, False),
    ((1, 2), False),
    (('test', ''), False),
    (('test', 1), False),
    (('test', 'testpw'), True),
])
def test_is_valid_credentials(credentials, expected):
    actual = is_valid_credentials(credentials)
    assert actual == expected
```

Comment: A very interesting question, though I don't think it's particularly on topic. First, your claim that _when is_valid_credentials returns true, credentials is of type tuple[str, str]_ is only true in one direction. It's possible for the tuple to be properly typed and the return value to be false.

Comment: Welcome to the Code Review Community. We only review code that is working as expected, there are other sites that will help you debug your code. Please read [Where can I get help?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-sites-do-i-post-on) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Asking to solve a specific issue with your code is not really appropriate for Code Review. This looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), though. The probable advice is that your design is bad, and you shouldn't be doing it this way at all. There is probably a way to reframe your question such that you are seeking open-ended feedback, if you provide more context, retitle the question according to [ask], and downgrade the typing issue from a demand to a concern about a code smell.

Answer (score 4):

Currently MyPy does not know that the function `is_valid_credentials` is a type guard that narrows the type of the passed credentials

Introduced in Python 3.10 [`typing.TypeGuard`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeGuard) can be used to annotate a type guard function with the narrowed type if `True` is returned

```py
from typing import TypeGuard  # use `typing_extensions` for Python 3.9 and below

def is_valid_credentials(credentials: MaybeCredentials) -> TypeGuard[Tuple[str, str]]:
    ...

def validate(credentials: MaybeCredentials) -> Optional[tuple[str, str]]:
    if is_valid_credentials(credentials):
        return credentials # Now narrowed to Tuple[str, str]
    return None
```

[MyPy docs](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/type_narrowing.html#user-defined-type-guards)

Comment: That's nice. We've been using the method in my answer and must continue to do so as we're only on 3.8. I'm *definitely* creating a JIRA issue on Monday to use this feature when we get round to going 3.10.

Answer (score 1):

Consider your code:

```py
MaybeCredentials = Optional[Tuple[Optional[str], Optional[str]]]


def validate(credentials: MaybeCredentials) -> Optional[tuple[str, str]]:
    if is_valid_credentials(credentials):
        return credentials
    return None
```

The `credentials` variable already *has* a `MaybeCredentials` type and that type does *not* match the type being returned from the function. More correctly, the return type is a subset of the input type so the variable may need to be coerced into the smaller "type space".

We've found (in Python 3.8) that you must basically remove all the possibilities where the things that cannot be `None` in the return type are caught and guaranteed to be non-`None` (either by not using them in the return value at all, or turning them into something compatible).

I believe in your case that would be something like:

```py
MaybeCredentials = Optional[Tuple[Optional[str], Optional[str]]]


def validate(credentials: MaybeCredentials) -> Optional[tuple[str, str]]:
    if credentials is None:
        return None
    if credentials[0] is None:
        return None              # or set it to real string like ""?
    if credentials[1] is None:
        return None              # or set it to real string like ""?

    # Here, no part of the MaybeCredentials` is None.
    
    if is_valid_credentials(credentials):
        return credentials
    return None
```

---

As to the name, I *don't* think `validate` is a good one, since validation implies simply checking that a thing is "good". This function, as mentioned, is intended to *change* the thing into a different type.

In that case, you should be looking at verbs more apropos, such as `coerce`, `fix_up`, `modify`, `filter_nones`, or any other name that implies a modification to the variable/type-of-variable.